# How to get last record from table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table :

**TABLE A**

```
   ID (PK)(Identity seed)
   Key (nvarchar) (Unique Hashed Keys)
```

Data:

```
   ID          Key
   ----------- --------------------------------------------------
   1           ++0a4rZicJ68kProEpK/ig                            
   2           ++0Coy1S7szg3NjLi2kMLQ                            
   3           ++0eeYiZuRPxsiVVsBcfdg                            
   4           +F07I6n6kLvC/I98So8Y+w                            
   5           +f/RK7VMWIIo5IfUcMujmg
```

**TABLE B** : (Without PK)

```
   Content (nvarchar)
   SortKey (nvarchar)
```

Data :

```
   Content          SortKey 
   ----------- --------------------------------------------------
   TEST1           ++0a4rZicJ68kProEpK/ig                            
   TEST2           ++0Coy1S7szg3NjLi2kMLQ                            
   TEST3           ++0eeYiZuRPxsiVVsBcfdg                            
   TEST4           +F/ZdeGRjbC4sP6ulQnOvg                            
   TEST5           +f0+6vJcwY++Xdx5lch1kQ 
   TEST6           +f/RK7VMWIIo5IfUcMujmg <-- Expected Result starts here
   TEST7           +F07I6n6kLvC/I98So8Y+w
   TEST8           +f0990bHYJUOXkyME+0kmg
```

Query :

```
SELECT top 3 * 
FROM 
    TABLEB 
WHERE 
    SortKey > (SELECT top 1 Key 
               FROM TABLEA 
               ORDER BY ID DESC)
ORDER BY 
    SortKey
```

The above query gives me the desired result which is greater than the `SortKey` (++1l32JdpYoHzXTCIp4jSA):

```
TEST6           +f/RK7VMWIIo5IfUcMujmg 
TEST7           +F07I6n6kLvC/I98So8Y+w
TEST8           +f0990bHYJUOXkyME+0kmg
```

Once I get this result I need to get the final (last record) key again to do an insert on another table, so I need to get the key of `TEST8` in this scenario i.e. : f/RK7VMWIIo5IfUcMujmg.

How do I do this in a single query and not have to write 2 separate queries?

Comment: Sorry I just added random key, should've used correct ones let me see if I can correct that

Comment: Updated the Key column to have correct values, the sort should give results now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)()

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CONTENT DESC) rn,
      Content,
      SortKey
FROM   tableb 
WHERE  sortkey < (SELECT TOP 1 [key] 
                  FROM   tablea 
                  ORDER  BY id DESC) 
 )
SELECT 
     Content,
     SortKey 
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 1
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71806/11)

Comment: Why are we doing an ORDER BY on Content ? The content is just plain text and has no relevancy, the "key" is the main column in question.

Comment: @MurtazaMandvi I assumed that defined the "Last Record". If its sortkey you could use that instead. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the desired output?